# Scripting / Macro tools for Bluetooth etc on Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth, macros, autohotkey, script

Say I have to connect a Bluetooth headset, it takes a long time to do it manually each time (and afterwards its the sound settings).

What kind of scripting or macro tools would I use to automate this.

One candidate seems to be  [Autohotkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autohotkey), but it seems to be more about launcing the actions than programming them.

Answer (score 2):

Autohotkey could definitly be your choice. Following conceptuel possibilities:

1) Script the mouse clicks to do so. That is a bit of work in AHK

2) Launch the bluetooth menu via AHK (e.g. see http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/83571-autohotkey-connect-to-bluetooth/ ). This still requires one click then, you could also script that on.

I'm not yet satisfied with these so please share further insights.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this because Windows 8 loves to autoconnect to my s305 headset, even though I often want to connect it to my phone, and Windows//my particular set-up is very greedy, refusing to release connection.

My solution is a hotkey that disables the bluetooth service, which I use before turning on the headset. (see my old method for auto connecting in the comment, I just made a link to the headset connection command)

> ^!+b:: EnvGet, DROPBOX, DROPBOX Run
>   %DROPBOX%\Code\Services\utils\batcommands\bstop.lnk 
>   ;Run explorer.exe "C:\Users\s9b\Dropbox\Install and Setup\Win7Files\s305.lnk" 
>   return
>   ^!+n:: EnvGet, DROPBOX, DROPBOX Run
>   %DROPBOX%\Code\Services\utils\batcommands\bstart.lnk 
>   return

(disabling a service with dependencies requires admin access, so I use an admin-access-enabled .lnk to a .bat file)

bat files just say:
net stop bthserv
and
net start bthserv
net start bthHFSrv

But back to your question. It seems someone over in the [autohotkey forums](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/2306-changing-default-audio-device/) found a way to change the registry value for the default audio device.

> ; Toggle Sound Devices !+s::
>       RegRead, Device, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Sound Mapper, Playback
>       if(Device = "Realtek HD Audio output")
>       {
>           RegWrite, REG_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Sound Mapper, Playback, Sound Blaster
>   Audigy
>           Device := "Audigy"
>       }
>       else
>       {
>           RegWrite, REG_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Sound Mapper, Playback, Realtek HD Audio
>   output
>           Device := "Realtek"
>       }
>
> ```
> ToolTip, % "Sound Device: " Device
> SetTimer, ResetToolTip, 1000 return
> ```